# jQuery: Wrapping every 2 loop-appended elements

Tags: jquery, loops, append

I'm working with Google's feed API and trying to append and wrap my markup in a certain way. I started with an example.

I've found a number of answers to this question for existing markup, but I'm having trouble applying it to markup appended in a loop. I suspect this is simpler than I'm making it, but haven't yet been able to find an elegant solution.

I'd like to wrap each 2 of the looped, appended `<li>` into a `<ul>` like this:

```
<div id="result">
    <ul>
        <li><a ...></li>
        <li><a ...></li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
        <li><a ...></li>
        <li><a ...></li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
        <li><a ...></li>
        <li><a ...></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Here's my simplified code:

```
<!doctype html>
<head>
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src='http://www.google.com/jsapi?key=[ key ]'></script><script>
    google.load("feeds", "1");
    $(function(){
      var feed = new google.feeds.Feed("[ feed URL ]");
      feed.load(function(result) {
        if (result.error)return;

        $feed = $('#result');

        for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
          var entry = result.feed.entries[i];

          $feed.append(
            '<li>'+
            '<a class="headline" href="'
            + entry.link +
            '">'
            + entry.title +
            '</a><span>'
            + entry.publishedDate + 
            ' | ' 
            + entry.author + 
            '</span></li>'
            );
        }
      });
    });
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="articles">
    <div id="result">

    </div>
  </div><!-- e .articles -->
</body>
</html>
```

What can I add to make this work?

Answer (score 1):

You are already iterating over all the results with your `for` loop.

You could just check if you are on position 0, 2 or 4 by using the [javascript modulus operator](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/JavaScript/0040__Operators/Modulus.htm) and add the `<ul>` and `</ul>` tags accordingly

e.g. in the for loop open the `ul` tag

```
if (i%2 == 0)
   $feed.append('<ul>' + '<li>' ...);
```

and close the `ul` tag

```
if (i%2 == 1)
   $feed.append(... '</li>' + '</ul>');
```

**Side note**: More elegantly you could use the [jQuery each function](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/) to iterate over the array.